# Django NoReverseMatch Error with templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

friends, I'm struggling with a NoReverseMatch error for a few days, and I can't seem to find what is wrong with the code. I must say I am quite new to Django, So I would appreciate it very much if you explain your solution to the problem so I could learn from it :)

The Error

```
NoReverseMatch at /david/Physics/
Reverse for 'subcategory' with keyword arguments '{'subcategory_name': 'a'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['david/([a-zA-Z_]+)/(?P<subcategory_name>[a-zA-Z_]+)/$']
```

category.html:

```
<h1>The subcategories for {{ category }}</h1>
{% if subcategories %}
    <ul>
    {% for subcategory in subcategories %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'subcategory' subcategory_name=subcategory %}">{{ subcategory }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <h4>No subcategories for that category</h4>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^browse/$', views.browse, name='browse'),
    url(r'^(?P<category_name>[a-zA-Z_]+)/$', views.view_category, name='category'),
    url(r'^([a-zA-Z_]+)/(?P<subcategory_name>[a-zA-Z_]+)/$',
        views.view_subcategory, name='subcategory'),
    url(r'^([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/(?P<information>[a-zA-Z_]+)/$',
        views.view_information, name='information'),
    ]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_list_or_404, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse 

from .models import Category, Subcategory

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'basic_web/index.html')

def search(request):
    return HttpResponse('Here you can search!')

def browse(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {'categories': categories}
    return render(request, 'basic_web/browse.html', context)

def view_category(request, category_name):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category,name__iexact=category_name)
    subcategories = get_list_or_404(Subcategory, parent=category)
    context = {'subcategories': map(lambda x: str(x), subcategories)}
    return render(request, 'basic_web/category.html', context)

def view_subcategory(request, subcategory_name):
    return HttpResponse('You are now browsing subcategory %s' % subcategory_name)

def view_information(request, information):
    return HttpResponse('You are now seeing %s' % information)
```

If I need to supply more information, please do tell me :)
Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two capturing groups in your subcategory URL pattern (and three in your information one). This means that it would match something like:

```
/param1/subcategory_name/
```

You don't give a name to the first group, and you're not passing it in your `{% url %}` tag. Are you sure you want it? You should probably remove it so that your pattern becomes

```
r'^(?P<subcategory_name>[a-zA-Z_]+)/$',
```

If on the other hand you do actually need it, you should give it a name:

```
 url(r'^(?P<param_name>[a-zA-Z_]+)/(?P<subcategory_name>[a-zA-Z_]+)/$',
```

and pass it when you need the URL:

```
{% url 'subcategory' param_name=param subcategory_name=subcategory %}
```

Perhaps the first parameter is meant to be the category?